# sql query for searching within columns with json documents

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I am using MySQL 5.7 and one of the columns in my table contains multiple JSON documents. Some thing like:

```
'[ {
  "animal" : "dog",
  "data" : {
    "body" : "This sentence does not contain any thing about grooming",
  }
},
{
  "animal" : "cat",
  "data" : {
    "body" : "No grooming needed"
  }
},
{

  "animal" : "horse",
  "data" : {
    "body" : "He is grooming his horse after the ride."
  }
}
]'
```

I want to return all rows where **$.data.body** contains *grooming* more than once, but only if **$.animal == horse**. So in the example given above it should not return the row since *grooming* is used only once in the section **$.data.body** where **$.animal == horse**.

Is there a good way to query this in MySql/SQL? I can do it in python but interested in knowing if there's a way to do this in SQL/MySQL. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Searching JSON requires complex queries, and it is hard to optimize:

```
SELECT ...
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(myjsoncolumn, '$[*]' COLUMNS(
  animal varchar(20) PATH '$.animal',
  body text PATH '$.data.body'
)) AS j 
WHERE j.animal = 'horse' AND j.body LIKE '%grooming%';
```

The [JSON_TABLE() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) is available in MySQL 8.0.4, but not earlier versions of MySQL.

The bottom line is that if you are trying to search the content of JSON documents, your use of SQL is going to be a lot more difficult and less efficient.

This would be far easier if you did not store the data in JSON, but instead stored data in normal rows and columns. From the example you show, there's no reason it needs to be JSON.

Comment: Unfortunately I am on an older version 5.7. Is there anything equivalent in there? Either ways thanks for the answer.

Comment: There is no equivalent function for MySQL 5.7. Your options are to store your data in a normal fashion instead of JSON, or upgrade to MySQL 8.0, or shorten your life by several years by solving this with some regular expression.